# Rails 4.2 routing: deep and dynamic defaults for params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm looking to reuse controllers while maintaining pretty links for different resources.

Let's say there are articles, users and comments in the system.

Comments controller index action takes a hash parameter named `filter_params` and does the filtering. So if `params[:filter_params][:user_id]` has value `1`, it will display all comments by user with ID `1`. Similarly with articles and `article_id`.

What I'm looking for is to have the following routes work:

1. `/users/1/comments`, to `comments#index`, params `{ filter_params: { user_id: 1 } }`
2. `/articles/1/comments`, to `comments#index`, params `{ filter_params: { article_id: 1 } }`
3. `/articles/1/comments?filter_params[user_id]=1`, to `comments#index`, params `{ filter_params: { article_id: 1, user_id: 1 } }`

My initial idea was to use `defaults` option for routes and construct the default `filter_params` there. But that seems to accept only a static hash instead of a proc where I could access the request. And on top of that, it would not work with 3rd example, since defaults can't get overwritten and subsequently `?filter_params[user_id]=1` would get ignored.

So is there a way to make it work with only the router? Or should I give up and create a `before_filter` in `CommentsController` that stuffs `params[:user_id]` and `params[:article_id]` into `params[:filter_params]`?